# Day scheduler calender for Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-ui, jquery

I am making a mobile web site and i need a a day scheduler like

```
     http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (including the hourly scheduler)
```

but it has to be optimized for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. `dhtmlxScheduler` has a mobile version of the event calendar. The code is licensed under GPL.